# Visual studio Build Task Issue for PowerShell inline task - Azure

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, powershell-3.0, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-pipelines-build-task

I am running a vsts build inline PowerShell script task to create package for Azure cloud service. It works fine and create package file from my local machine, but when I try to run from VSTS PowerShell inline task it gives error :

**##[error]Cannot find path ‘D:\a_tasks\InlinePowershell_31f040e5-e040-4336-878a-59a493355534\1.1.6\ServiceConfiguration.Cloud.Test.cscfg’ because it does not exist.**

Here is my PowerShell inline script below, It fails on the following line:

```
Copy-Item $serviceConfigurationPath $packageOutDir
```

I really appreciate your help on this.

Thanks,

```
# This is the VSTS repository path
$workingDirectory = “$/DevCodeBase/ToolDevBranch1.33”
$webProjectName = “WebRole1”
$cloudProjectName = ‘ProjAzureDeployment’
$evv =’Test’
$cppack = ‘C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\.NET SDK\v2.9\bin\cspack.exe’
$solutionDir = [string]::Format(“{0}”, $workingDirectory)
$webDir = [string]::Format(“{0}\{1}”, $workingDirectory, $webProjectName)
$packageOutDir = [string]::Format(“{0}\{1}”, $workingDirectory, $cloudProjectName)
$rolePropertyFile = [string]::Format(“{0}\{1}\{2}”, $workingDirectory, $cloudProjectName, “roleproperties.txt”)
# Create Role Properties File – This property file specifies the .Net framework against which webrole is going to run.
New-Item $rolePropertyFile -Type file -Force -Value “TargetFrameWorkVersion=v4.5” | Out-Null
New-Item $packageOutDir -Type directory -Force | Out-Null
# CSPack command Definition
$serviceDefinitionPath = [string]::Format(“{0}\{1}\ServiceDefinition.csdef”, $solutionDir, $cloudProjectName)
if ($evv -eq “Test”){
$serviceConfigurationPath = “ServiceConfiguration.Cloud.Test.cscfg”
}
else
{
$serviceConfigurationPath = [string]::Format(“{0}\{1}\ServiceConfiguration.Cloud.cscfg”, $solutionDir, $cloudProjectName)
}
$serviceRole = [string]::Format(“/role:{0};{1}”, $webProjectName, $webDir)
$rolePropertiesFile = [string]::Format(“/rolePropertiesFile:{0};{1}”, $webProjectName, $rolePropertyFile)
$sites = [string]::Format(“/sites:{0};Web;{1}”, $webProjectName, $webDir)
$packageOutput = [string]::Format(“/out:{0}\{1}.cspkg”, $packageOutDir, $cloudProjectName)
# $packageOutput = [string]::Format(“{0}\{1}.cspkg”, $packageOutDir, $cloudProjectName)
Write-Host $packageOutput
Write-Host $serviceConfigurationPath
# Build CSPKG file
& “C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\.NET SDK\v2.9\bin\cspack.exe” $serviceDefinitionPath $serviceRole $rolePropertiesFile $sites $packageOutput /useCtpPackageFormat | Out-Null
Write-Host $serviceDefinitionPath
Write-Host $serviceRole
Write-Host $rolePropertiesFile
Write-Host $sites
Write-Host $packageOutput
Write-Host ‘before copy’
# Copy configuration file
Copy-Item $serviceConfigurationPath $packageOutDir
# Remove Role Properties File
Remove-Item -Path $rolePropertyFile -Force | Out-Null
```

Comment: Do you solve this issue with Niels's solution? (You need to change this code: `if ($evv -eq “Test”){
$serviceConfigurationPath = “ServiceConfiguration.Cloud.Test.cscfg”
}`)

Comment: yes, I changed to following code, but still I have same issue.[string]::Format(“{0}\{1}\ServiceConfiguration.Cloud.Test.cscfg”, $solutionDir, $cloudProjectName)

Comment: Do you change $workingDirectory to the actual path (not the server path, e.g. `$workingDirectory="$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\ToolDevBranch1.33"`)

Comment: I added following line for packageout directory, now it is copy

Comment: I added following line for packageout directory, now it is copying only cscfg file not cspkg file. $artifactDirectory = "$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)" . it is failing in following line :         # Build CSPKG file
    & "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\.NET SDK\v2.9\bin\cspack.exe" $serviceDefinitionPath $serviceRole $rolePropertiesFile $sites $packageOutput /useCtpPackageFormat | Out-Null

Comment: What's the detail error message? On the other hand, you just copy cscfg file not others (`Copy-Item $serviceConfigurationPath $packageOutDir`).

Answer (score 1):

In the VSTS task you'll have to specify an absolute path, otherwise the script will look in the temporary directory created for your inline powershell script.

For instance, you could supply the path to the file as a parameter like
-filepath "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\Solution\config.json"

(For a list of the variables you can use, have a peek [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/definitions/build/variables?tabs=batch#predefined-variables))

If you  want to keep using a relative path, you can move to a file based (ie non-inline) script and use a relative path to that.